# Error when calling gimp-drawable-set-pixel in gimp's python console

Tags: python, gimp, python-fu

I'm typing this code directly into Gimp's Python Console:

```
img=gimp.image_list()[0]
drw = pdb.gimp_image_active_drawable(img)
gimp-drawable-set-pixel(drw,x,y,3,[0xff,0x00,0x00])
```

and it's yeilding this error after calling the gimp-drawable-set-pixel function:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'drawable' is not defined
```

It yields the same error when called with four bytes instead of three bytes as well.

I'm using gimp 2.8.10 on Ubuntu 14.04.01 x86_64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a typo of [`gimp_drawable_set_pixel`](http://oldhome.schmorp.de/marc/pdb/gimp_drawable_set_pixel.html).

```
pdb.gimp_drawable_set_pixel(drw,x,y,3,[0xff,0x00,0x00])
```

Comment: then I get `NameError: name 'gimp_drawable_set_pixel' is not defined`, but I think you are on to something.

Comment: @Tyzoid, What happend if you qualify the function with `pdb.` ?

Comment: It is not a "typo" - the GIMP Procedure browser shows the procedures with the Scheme (script-fu) friendly name, which uses "-" as word separator. In Python and all C derived languages, that would just mean a subtraction, so "_" is used. If one click on the "browse" button at the bottom of the Python console, and browse through there, there is an "apply" button which pastes the correct name in the console already.